# Load .3ds model with high number of polygons - Helix Toolkit Sharp DX

Tags: c#, wpf, sharpdx, 3d-model, helix-3d-toolkit

I used HelixToolkit a couple of f times before, and I managed to load my model (all were small-sized models), and they all worked properly. Now, I have many models with lots of polygons for a project (some have about 10000 polygons). So, when I ran my program, I got an error: "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Non-negative number required.'

So, I googled the problem, and somebody mentioned that he uses Helix Sharp DX for his large models. I tried Helix Sharp DX. My XAML code is something like this:

```
<helix:Viewport3DX x:Name="Viewport3D" ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True">
      <helix:GroupModel3D x:Name ="LoadedModels" />
</helix:Viewport3DX>
```

And my C# code is something like this:

```
Viewport3D.Items.Add(new DirectionalLight3D() { Direction = new System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Vector3D(-1, -1, -1) });
var reader = new HelixToolkit.Wpf.SharpDX.StudioReader();
var model = reader.Read(path);
foreach (var modelPart in model)
{
    var sharpModel = new MeshGeometryModel3D()
    {
        Geometry = modelPart.Geometry,
        //Material = modelPart.Material, 
        Name = modelPart.Name,
        //Transform = new MatrixTransform3D(modelPart.Transform.ToMatrix3D())
    };
    LoadedModels.Children.Add(sharpModel);
}
```

But, I again got the same error. I wonder if there is any problem with my code; or if we should try to reduce the number of polygons.
Any help/suggestion regarding this issue is appreciated. I prefer to solve it via coding since the polygon count reduction will take most of the time of the project timeline.

Thanks

Comment: Probably something wrong with the model itself? 10000 polygon is small. It would be helpful if you can get the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @LanceH I reopened the model in a 3D modeling application. It seems fine. I should try another application and export it again. I couldn't find any resource that shows the maximum number of supported polygon counts for SharpDX, so, I thought maybe it is because it is a big model. I try to trace the stack. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: There is no hard limit on polygon counts, usually it depends on your device and memory. Usually render millions of polygon is fine for modern graphics card. The exception usually indicates there is an negative values being read, but expected positive values, probably check your model indices whether there is an negative index in it.

Comment: @LanceH I tried to open my 3D model using another 3D modeling application, and it seems the model has problems :( Thanks for your advice. Now I can open my model using HelixToolkit. However, in large models, it responds really slow. But, at least I got that the code has no errors. Thanks again.

Comment: Slow, you mean loading slow or rendering slow.

Comment: both, I think. It takes about 40 secs to show the model in the first place. Then When I rotate it, it rotates slowly, and it is not a smooth rotation, just shows a couple of frames in between, and then the model is in its final position.

Comment: Are you sure the model only contains 10000 polygons? What is your graphics card model?

Comment: @Lance H First I am sorry for my late reply. Actually, I asked the person who gave me the model to control the model polygon count again. And it has more than 10000 polygons she told me at the beginning. So, she tries to reduce the polygon counts and I will try it again. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hove you be any chance seen the coordinates of your object? I have encountered the same problem and it seems that the error may be due to the fact that the polygons (triangles) are missing from your .OBJ file. See if you object has lines similar to these: `f 7078 7089 7045`

Comment: @FAFernández Well, since I couldn't find any solution, we converted our models to obj format, and now they open in a matter of seconds according to the size of the file. And also I didn't have to use the Helix Toolkit Sharp DX, I used the Helix toolkit.